# How separately install KSQLdb amid Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I wonder separately install KSQLdb amid Kafka when Kafka was installed from officail distributive?

Comment: Is there a specific installation issue you're having?

Comment: I can not find information how to install, just one sample from official web site, but they offers docket image. But it need to do that manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is no standalone package](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/ksqldb/index.html#ksqldb-standalone-and-ksqldb-for-cp)

The Docker image mentioned in the docs is built from the source code on Github, then configures the `ksql-server.properties` file and runs `ksql-server-start`, which is what you would need to do as well, starting with `mvn package` of the source, then finding the appropriate rest-server JAR files

You can also [chime in on this Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2568) with the same question